# prestashop : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document

Tags: php, xml, web-services, prestashop

I'm using PSWebServiceLibrary.php for prestashop and in the `add` function this is the code which send the xml request for parsning. I have

```
        self::checkStatusCode($request['status_code']);
        $res = trim($request['response'] ); 
        var_dump($res);
        return self::parseXML($request['response']);
```

And this is the output of var_dump :

```
string(1459) "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<customer>
    <id><![CDATA[220]]></id>
    <id_default_group></id_default_group>
    <id_lang xlink:href="http://elpakhsh.com/api/languages/2"><![CDATA[2]]></id_lang>
    <newsletter_date_add><![CDATA[2017-07-12 10:50:46]]></newsletter_date_add>
    <ip_registration_newsletter></ip_registration_newsletter>
    <last_passwd_gen><![CDATA[2017-07-12 04:50:46]]></last_passwd_gen>
    <secure_key><![CDATA[95bb810ab3d387bc7eb249030ec06233]]></secure_key>
    <deleted></deleted>
    <passwd><![CDATA[e95db4822affea261aad478059f75457]]></passwd>
    <lastname><![CDATA[مشتری]]></lastname>
    <firstname><![CDATA[مشتری]]></firstname>
    <email><![CDATA[navid.abutorab@gmail.com]]></email>
    <id_gender></id_gender>
    <birthday></birthday>
    <newsletter><![CDATA[1]]></newsletter>
    <optin><![CDATA[1]]></optin>
    <website></website>
    <company></company>
    <siret></siret>
    <ape></ape>
    <outstanding_allow_amount></outstanding_allow_amount>
    <show_public_prices></show_public_prices>
    <id_risk></id_risk>
    <max_payment_days></max_payment_days>
    <active><![CDATA[1]]></active>
    <note></note>
    <is_guest></is_guest>
    <id_shop><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop>
    <id_shop_group><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop_group>
    <date_add><![CDATA[2017-07-12 10:50:46]]></date_add>
    <date_upd><![CDATA[2017-07-12 10:50:46]]></date_upd>
<associations>
<groups nodeType="group" api="groups"/>
</associations>
</customer>
</prestashop>"
```

As you can see from the output, There is no whitespace at the beginning but I still got the error that says

> HTTP XML response is not parsable: array ( 0 =>
>   LibXMLError::__set_state(array( 'level' => 3, 'code' => 64, 'column'
>   => 7, 'message' => 'XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document ', 'file' => '', 'line' => 1, )), )

What's the problem?is there anything wrong with my xml ??I have validate it and it got no problem ..

Comment: Your printing a trimmed version of the text, try changing last line to `return self::parseXML($res);`

Comment: @NigelRen It was without trim at the first time but no difference

Comment: @hamid.jdd It should work. Check https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/pull/47/commits/2131ad7733b2a27dca5fb14b29e1542f0d30b621.